# sed not able to print matching regex grop only

Tags: regex, linux

I have some key value pair arguments. I need to print them as is.
Example.

```
echo $X
(a=b) (c=d) (e=f)
echo "$X" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*=[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/match/1'
echo "$X" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*=[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/\1/1'
echo "$X" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*=[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/\1/2'
echo "$X" | sed -E 's/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*=[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/\1/3'
```

Post the above expresion, I wanted to print matching groups one by one. using .* in pattern matching is greedy and is printing either first or last matching groups only. How can I print any matching group in this way.

Here is my expected output.

```
a=b
c=d
e=f
```

Comment: Should the script check for errors in the input? What output do you expect if the input contains something that doesn't match your pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `) (` with a newline and remove the remaining parentheses.

```
echo "$X" | sed 's/) (/\n/g;s/[()]//g'
```

To print the `$n`th line, you can pipe the output to

```
sed -n "$n p"
```

Answer (score 2):

This grep one-liner will do:

```
grep -o '[^(]*=[^)]*'
```

example:

```
kent$  grep -o '[^(]*=[^)]*' <<<'(a=b) (c=d) (e=f)' 
a=b
c=d
e=f
```